# Elementary OS Loki mouse acceleration

Tags: mouse, elementary-os, settings

My problem is that I prefer mouse acceleration (or "precision" mode), but elementary does not seem to support it.

I have tried various settings like `xset m 40`, and I have installed `gpointing-device-settings` which does not seem to do anything.

When the OS boots and just my wallpaper is shown, my mouse for some reason works with acceleration (like it did when I had Ubuntu) but after a while the screen goes black for a second, the top bar is shown, my startup applications start, and the mouse goes back to its default state!

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: One of my autostart applications contains `Exec=xset m 5/2 12`.  Might it be that your system contains a similar autostart, overriding your preferred settings?

Comment: Well I checked and the only startup applications are Dropbox and Redshift, + the problem happened before I installed them.